# How to Register Middleware in HostingStartup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

#### background

I hope to add additional middleware by registering the plugin **without changing the original project code**, but how to get the `IApplicationBuilder` required to register the middleware **in the plugin** is the biggest problem I currently face.
According to the [*Hosting Startup Document*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1), the plugin can be registered by inheriting `IHostingStartup` and loaded automatically when the project starts, E.g:

```
// plugin
public class MyStartup: IHostingStartup
{
     // Implement the IHostingStartup interface
     public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
     {
         // TODO: I want to get an IApplicationBuilder object to register middleware
     }
}
```

#### question

How to get `IApplicationBuilder` object by `IWebHostBuilder`?

Comment: middleware registration is related to the main project, not the plugin. 
do you have access to the original project code?

Comment: I want to make a plugin to adapt to different projects, and can install or uninstall them at any time, so I want to reduce the changes to the project source code, it is best not to make changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the official docs, [Extend Startup with startup filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1#extend-startup-with-startup-filters) explains that [`IStartupFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupfilter?view=aspnetcore-3.1) might be useful here:

> Use `IStartupFilter` to configure middleware at the beginning or end of an app's `Configure` middleware pipeline without an explicit call to `Use{Middleware}`.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class MyStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
            next(app);
        };
    }
}
```

In this example, we're adding `MyMiddleware` to the *beginning* of the pipeline, which means that it runs *before* the rest of the pipeline. To run `MyMiddleware` at the *end* of the pipeline, switch the order of `app.UseMiddleware` and `next`.

You must also register this implementation with the DI container, like this:

```
// plugin
public class MyStartup : IHostingStartup
{
     // Implement the IHostingStartup interface
     public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
     {
         builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
         {
             services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, MyStartupFilter>();
         });
     }
}
```

Although this works, it's not as flexible as you might need it to be. For example, it doesn't allow you to inject middleware *between* middleware added by the app.